# Very High CPU usage by pulseaudio process. How can I kill it

Tags: pulseaudio, cpu

So I noticed my laptop fans are always audible whenever I start Ubuntu (This doesn't happen on Windows) I used `top` to check running processes and I find a process called `pulseaudio` using around 70-90% of the %CPU which I believe is very high for an audio management process, I tried to kill it using `sudo pkill` but it just keeps respawning, I am not sure what to do since I am an Ubuntu newcomer and I really started to love it, please help :/

Comment: Check if you have the process `orca` may also be there when you run the `top` command? then provably you have had a screen reader triggered accidentally.